# chartSeries bounds: setting par("usr") equal to itself changes the axes

Tags: r, graph, quantmod

I'm trying to set the bounds on a graph so I can plot indicators, then move/squish the bounds so I can plot points in the same place. However, I'm having trouble just getting started since when I change the bounds to itself the relative axis appears to change.

example:

```
                     Open  High   Low Close
2014-06-15 23:16:26 13798 13800 13797 13799
2014-06-15 23:38:13 13799 13800 13797 13798
2014-06-15 23:59:59 13798 13800 13794 13798
2014-06-16 00:21:39 13798 13800 13795 13796
2014-06-16 00:43:11 13796 13799 13795 13798
```

Now the following code will draw two different rectangles, the second slightly higher and to the right by about 14x6 pixels

```
> par("usr")
[1]     0.44    15.56 13793.76 13800.24
> rect(1,13796,4,13798)
> par(usr=par("usr"))
> rect(1,13796,4,13798)
> par("usr")
[1]     0.44    15.56 13793.76 13800.24
```

This is pretty infuriating... what I'm trying to fix is the fact that this happens when I try to plot an indicator... the bounds are automatically moved:

```
> par("usr")
[1]     0.44    15.56 13793.76 13800.24
> addMACD(slow=2,fast=1,signal=1)
> par("usr")
[1]  0.440000000 15.560000000 -0.008219178  0.008219178
```

Comment: To "change" `par("usr")` to itself, shouldn't the code be `par(usr=par("usr"))`?

Comment: whoops, yeah that's what I did the first time, I'll edit

Comment: oh looks like it does the same thing with either `par("usr"=par("usr"))` or `par(usr=par("usr"))`. Also note that `par({other parameter}={itself})` doesn't change anything from the handful I tried